# How to execute a script again after click button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML template with an external script to manage cookies permissions:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="fr">
    <head>
      <script id="consentementCookiesScript"  src="https://static.desjardins.com/fw/cookie/scriptCookie.js" ></script>
```

The cookies permissions' language is set according with the Lang att into the tag html.
I manage creating a btn to change dynamically the Lang att:

```html
<div id="toolbar" class="toolbar">
  <div id="changeLangElement" style="color: white">Français</div>
</div>
```

through this function:

```js
changeLangElement.onclick = function () {
  currentLang = currentLang === "fr" ? "en" : "fr";
  translatePage(currentLang);
  document.documentElement.lang = currentLang;
};
```

Is there any way to execute the script again with the right language after click the button?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add an Event listener attached to that button or div like this  :

```
const changeLangElement = document.querySelector('#changeLangElement') ; 

changeLangElement.addEventListener('click' , () => {
  currentLang = currentLang === "fr" ? "en" : "fr";
  translatePage(currentLang);
  document.documentElement.lang = currentLang;
}) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either move the `currentLang` variable outside of the function scope or use **closure** like so:

```js
function createLangToggleHandler() {
  let currentLang = "en";

  return function () {
    currentLang = currentLang === "fr" ? "en" : "fr";
    translatePage(currentLang);
    document.documentElement.lang = currentLang;
  };
}

const changeLangElement = document.getElementById("changeLang");
changeLangElement.onclick = createLangToggleHandler();
```